# Contact form 7 not getting email

Tags: wordpress, email, contact-form-7

I'm using contact form 7 and facing a problem with this email id, I'm not getting any mail what we can do for that. I used SMTP also.
could you please suggest me any other option.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked spam folder ? Perhaps emails are in spam for email not get in spam you can use https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/

Here is setup documentation https://wpforms.com/docs/how-to-set-up-smtp-using-the-wp-mail-smtp-plugin/.

Please check may be helpful for you.

Comment: already I used that mail SMTP plugin. as well as according to you gave that link I followed but I did not get any result. please can you tell me its very important,

Comment: have you checked with email change ? Is there any error in mail tab in contact form 7 setting ? Please check this link https://contactform7.com/setting-up-mail/

Comment: yeah I changed email also and there is not getting any error message, basically, that form is submitted properly but that data is not getting on my mail id.

Comment: It can be that the emails sent get such a high spam score (for some reason) on the receivers end that does not even make it to the spam folder. Try generating an email address on http://www.isnotspam.com/ or any of the simular services to check the spam rating.

Comment: Hiiiii basically I looked my contact form 7 plugin is I think not working. that's why actually I create one more new form and tried but that form also not worked. so what we can do without uninstalling.

Comment: Hii , sorry for late reply so i think you need to tell this issue to your hosting provider and one temporary solution is you need to install Contact form 7 db plugin to get data of submitted your all contact form.You can further export it in csv using this plugin.Using this plugin you can see list of record form wise in your admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

The best option is using PhpMailer library in php. You can check if the email was sent successfully using php mailer. All you need to do is to take all the library code and add it to your FTP or install it using composer.

> Here is a simple example.

```
<?php
// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

// Load Composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                       // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'user@example.com';                     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'secret';                               // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                                  // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
    $mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
    $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
    $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

    // Attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name

    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

> You can get all the information on PhpMailer here [Php Mailer On Github](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

The PhpMailer is well configured so you don't have to worry about your emails ending up in Spam folder. Also be careful on the number of mails you send periodically to single recipients.